# How can I find out if a comma separated list contains a value?

Tags: c#, .net, string, csv

I have:

```
var a1 = "1,2,12,13";
var a2 = "2,12,13";

var b1 = a1.Contains(1); // Should give true
var b2 = a2.Contains(1); // Should give false
```

How can I find out if the string a contains the value of 1 rather than just any 1?

Comment: What is your question? 'rather than just any 1?'

Comment: @Sajeetharan quite bad phrasing and grammar, but I think OP wants to check if any of the **comma-separated values** is the number 1, rather than checking if any of the **characters** is a `'1'`.

Comment: @OP: this is trivial. Split the string on comma, and apply `Contains` to the resulting array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this extension method. Keep in mind that if anything is wrong with your input string then this will throw exception, you can add exception handling to it if you want. (like using `int.TryParse` or supporting different separator instead of comma)

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsInt(this string str, int value)
    {
        return str.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()))
            .Contains(value);
    }
}
```

this will split your string by `,` so you'll have all of your numbers but in string representation. Then you try to convert them to integer values. after that you check that if these values contains the integer value you want.
use it like this

```
var a1 = "1,2,12,13";
var a2 = "2,12,13";

var b1 = a1.ContainsInt(1); // gives true
var b2 = a2.ContainsInt(1); // gives false
```

---

If you want to use it without extension method you can do this

```
var a1 = "1,2,12,13";
var a2 = "2,12,13";

var b1 = a1.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()))
            .Contains(1); // gives true

var b2 = a2.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()))
            .Contains(1); // gives false
```

Comment: @doctor - can you give an example of how to do this without an extension method also? Thanks

Comment: @doctor - I am getting an error System.Array does not contain a definition for select

Comment: add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @marifemac you can use Regex to check with pattern like (^1(\s){0,},)|(,(\s){0,}1(\s){0,},)

Comment: You can also cast searched value to a string and search for it, without parsing values from an array: `var b2 = a2.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Contains(1.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your string doesn't contain spaces you can use this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsValue(this string str, object value)
    {    
       return str.StartsWith(value.ToString()+",") ||  str.EndsWith(","+value) || str.Contains(","+value+",");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just `str.Replace(" ","")` beforehand.

Comment: Yes, or that. Good catch.

Comment: I used this snippet in one of my older, but currently used projects. SqlServer 2005 database has a table in which one column has a comma separated values.  And i made SURE that column didn't have spaces before saving data. So no need for removing spaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private bool IsFound(string input)
    {

        string[] a1_values = input.Split(',');


        foreach (string item in a1_values)
        {
            if (item == "1")
            {

               return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;

        }

    }
```

Comment: This would only check the first item, and the isFound variable is kind of pointless.

Comment: yes...you are correct, the isFound variable is pointless. I removed it. yes this checks whatever input you put in there so if you have more then run the method again

Comment: It will still only check the first value in a1_values (whatever a1 is). You need to move `return false;` outside the loop so it will check all the items. Otherwise it will just check the first one and return false.